# GCP Service accounts for storage not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have created Service accounts in GCP Console **IAM & Admin** > **Service Accounts** >>  ***Create***

Assigned *Storage Admin*, *Storage Object Admin*, *Storage Object Creator*

Created *Key* and downloaded json file

To test this service account I ran this command on GCP VM

```
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service-account.json 
Activated service account credentials for: [ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

Then I was able to cp file to storage bucket

```
$ gsutil cp image-src.txt gs://bucket-images
Copying file://image-src.txt [Content-Type=text/plain]...
/ [1 files][ 19.5 KiB/ 19.5 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/19.5 KiB.
```

But when I try to use `service-account.json` with node.js app I get

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
    at new ApiError (/ingester/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:59:15)
    at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/ingester/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:194:38)
    at Util.handleResp (/ingester/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:135:117)
    at retryRequest (/ingester/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:434:22)
    at onResponse (/ingester/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:206:7)
    at /ingester/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:170:17
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)
```

Am i creating service account correctly ?

Update : After v1gnus answer

I tried to get

```
cloudshell:~ $ gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
etag: ACAB
```

Then I tried to set policy

```
cloudshell:~ $ gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding xxx-123 --member serviceAccount:ingester@xxx-123.ia
m.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/storage.admin
    Updated IAM policy for project [xxx-123].
    bindings:
    ...
    - members:
      - serviceAccount:ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      role: roles/storage.admin
    - members:
      - serviceAccount:ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      role: roles/storage.objectAdmin
    - members:
      - serviceAccount:ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
      role: roles/storage.objectCreator
    etag: rfvtgyh-4Gw=
    version: 1
```

After this I still get this

```
cloudshell:~ $ gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
etag: ACAB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have an issue with the permissions on your service account

```
“Error: ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.”
```

You can view which role has been assigned to your Service Account by typing this [command](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#viewing-roles):

```
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy ingester@xxx-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

For more information on how to use Google Cloud Storage Node.js Client API check this [link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/)

Comment: The official documentation says the output will show only an etag value, If you have not assigned a role to the service account. You should then restart the process from the beginning and assign the designated role. You may try using the console if it helps.

Comment: I had to give permission to user on bucket. Which worked. Source https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/edit-bucket-permissions.html